# stock register VC & confirmation password? Available?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

before i go off and code my own, it seems like a natural that Parse supplies a proper password scenario for the register view controller, which includes the password confirmation textbox. I see the example setup in AnyWall but prefer not to go with the xib if possible. I see no mention of it, but realizing they took pains to create it for AnyWall, i went looking.

Perhaps because of their desire to have "Done" disabled until all was ready, and the required NSNotification setup made them decide not into include it? Just guessing. Thoughts?

{edit: is there any active parse forum, where those of use who are using parse can simply free-flow questions and thoughts? I understand this is *not* an official parse asset but they do direct us here now that the "forum" they offered is archived. But this is not very active, and many of us refuse to use Google assets.
SO is awesome, but would there be traction to setup a standard web forum where there is not as rigid a process and perhaps more people would just "talk"?}